# Unit test framework for Gstreamer application written in python

Tags: python, unit-testing, gstreamer, python-unittest, python-gstreamer

I wrote a python application that creates multiple udp streaming pipelines using the python gstreamer bindings (Gst1.0 module). Each pipeline contains one udpsrc and can contain multiple udpsink elements and is dynamically modifiable. The user can add/remove/modify source or sinks dynamically via a UI during runtime. It is working as per expectation. However, I am not sure how to unit test the application as it is very tightly coupled with the gst module.

Can anybody suggest a unit test framework or any other tips that might help me?

Comment: You just need to decouple your code using dependency injection so you can test in isolation.

Comment: Have you found anything, interesting? I'm wondering how to test a gst-rstp-server application. But with all the signals I don't know where to start

Comment: I eneded up 'mock'ing the Gst module. I figured it wasn't up to me to test that gstreamer works, but to make sure that my application runs in cohesion with it and handles the occasional errors thrown by it.